Cut to Fellowship funding while employed
I am a PhD student nearing the end of their program. I have been receiving funding through the form of a fellowship for the entirety of the program. The fellowship very specifically says it is NOT employment income, and that I am not required to work or render any service as a term of receiving this fellowship.
For this upcoming semester, my advisor and I agreed it is finally time to take on a sessional instructor position. I have done other work for the department/university such as marking and TA work but this is obviously going to be more time consuming. After applying for a position, I learned that there is a department policy that fellowship funding is cut by 50% while taking on a sessional instructor position. The reasoning of this policy is "This reduction is to recognize that work as a Sessional Instructor impacts the student's time available for thesis research."
Now, taking together this seems to imply that despite the wording, there actually were conditions to the fellowship i.e. research. What rubs me the wrong way about this though is that my fellowship was never dependant on my work before, it was explicitly not. I was not researching while I was in courses, and at various times throughout the program when I had other priorities. If this fellowship is explicitly not employment income, how is it they are able to now decide it depends on my research time?
I am incredibly privileged for any funding at all, and I don't want my position to be in jeopardy at all by appearing ungrateful. But I would like to know if this is a normal and acceptable policy? I tried contacting my Graduate Students Association and they never got back to me. I am considering approaching my advisor about it, but perhaps I shouldn't get in the way of what is already a good deal, since I am getting paid at all.

Will you also be paid for teaching the course? Is there a meaningful change in total income or just in the fellowship?

Stating that the fellowship is not employment income is probably to save you from having to pay employment taxes on it. So, while it may seem frustrating that it's been cut, it also might not be to your benefit to argue otherwise.

@Buffy Yes I will be paid for the course, my income will increase as a result.

@BryanKrause I would rather pay employment tax if it meant I also had employee protections... but I understand thats not the standard in the academic world.

@Karl If you are in the US, paying employment tax doesn't necessarily gain you any employee protections. I can't say for anywhere else.

@BryanKrause I am not in the US

@Karl Then maybe it does matter for that, you might get a more specific answer if you state where you actually are but also you may need to consult a lawyer if what you are after is actual legal advice, we can't provide that here.

You make it sound like the fellowship, by virtue of not being tied to specific required actions on your part, is just money for nothing, but it's not. It's clearly meant to support you in your activities as a PhD student (doing research, going to classes etc.). The actual problem here is that you applied for a position without being told this crucial information about it. It's quite understandable that you'd be disappointed/upset about this, but I don't recommend making a complaint that sounds to me very much like "I thought I was getting money for nothing but you lied, it turns out I am not!"

It would be helpful to know what country you are in - I'm guessing probably not the UK as it would be more typical to receive a stipend, although this otherwise sounds pretty similar to how stipends work here.

Oh, I clicked on OP's profile and they're in Canada. Maybe someone familiar with the Canadian system can answer!

What is the source of the fellowship?  The university that you are attending?

@Anonymous The source of the fellowship is jointly my advisor and the department of graduate studies. The policy comes from the Department of CS.

@AdamPřenosil This is very a helpful explanation and context. Best answer yet.

In the UK for example a lot of PhD stipends (which are not taxable) only allow a limit number of hours of non-PhD related work per week to maintain eligibility.

Payroll person here.  I am going to give a US perspective, but in general the ideas can apply to other countries, and you should seek out how this works for your country.
Stipend and salary/employment are not the same thing at all.  These are categories that are defined and regulated by the federal and state governments and cannot be determined by PIs.  Labor laws impact all these determinations.  In the US, we have the Fair Labor Standards Act which helps set expectations for minimum wages.  The Department of Labor defines a trainee and indicates various requirements for defining a person as a trainee. One impact of being declared a trainee is that FLSA no longer applies to that role -- this is why students do not make "minimum wage" -- because part of their training is considered to be a benefit.  You will see that item 4 specifically states,

"The employer that provides the training receives no immediate
advantage from the activities of the trainees or students and, on
occasion, his operations may even be impeded;"

In these cases, you can be paid a stipend which is not taxable through the employer but can be taxable to the employee.  It is very important for people who are paid a stipend to monitor their own taxes because the employer does not watch out for their tax liability.
One additional difference in the US is that stipends do not carry FICA.  Some people think that this is great because it's cheaper to support someone with a stipend.  This is not great for the employee.  Social Security will ask how many years you have paid into FICA, and if you are getting paid a stipend and do not have FICA paid on your behalf, then you are not receiving credit in the years required to take this benefit later in life.
US federal grants prohibit stipends because by definition stipends do not require the student to create value (see that quote above from the Department of Labor).  On the other hand, there are some federal training and fellowship grants that only use stipends because they are set up only for trainees, because the focus of the grant is the education of students and not specifically publications/research results.
So now to your question:

"What rubs me the wrong way about this though is that my fellowship was
never dependant on my work before, it was explicitly not. I was not
researching while I was in courses, and at various times throughout
the program when I had other priorities. If this fellowship is
explicitly not employment income, how is it they are able to now
decide it depends on my research time?"

If you are US-based, this is a misinterpretation of the concept of "work".  Part of why we can pay students less than the FLSA amount is because we consider their education to have value as well.  Tuition remission, e.g., is taxed in the US as well.  In order to receive a stipend in many programs, you do not have to produce "results", but you do have to be in good standing.  Your program can require that time is spent on coursework or "research" broadly and not necessarily that you must work on a PI's grant.  Working on the PI's grant is salary, but if you are just generally performing research on your thesis does not have to be classed as salary.  This is again a determination by the institution according to the applicable labor laws.
So thinking about this type of framework for another country; here's an example of where I would start reading for a country like Canada.  I do not know Canadian laws, so I cannot advise further.  You can consider reaching out to your institution's HR department for help understanding.

this answer applies to the US; OP mentions in a comment they are not in the US so things may be different for them
Stating that the fellowship is not employment income is probably to save you from having to pay employment taxes on it (and, also, to prevent the institution from having to pay their share of employment taxes). So, while it may seem frustrating that it's been cut, it also might not be to your benefit to argue otherwise.
There is a bit of a gray area here, but the claims are probably that the fellowship is there to support you undertaking an independent educational venture. While you're doing research, learning things to help you do research, etc, you're participating in that venture that the fellowship is supporting you for. If you're working as an instructor, that time is not doing the things that the fellowship is supporting you for, so even though what you are doing with the fellowship is "education" and not "work", if your time is spent doing other kinds of work then they're interpreting that as not spending as much time on your education. They should probably be careful about how this is described but I would guess that they think a lawyer could argue "time available for thesis research" counts as "education" and not "work".

And in the US, the fellowship likely would be income and you would likely need to file income tax. Also note that, for example, the NSF states: "Stipends may be considered taxable income. Fellows bear the responsibility of filing and paying any taxes due."

@JonCuster There's a difference in the US between taxable income you pay income tax on and taxable employment income that you also pay Medicare, Social Security, etc on. Fellowship income not used directly for education expenses like tuition is taxed as income but skips all those other employment taxes, which add up to quite a lot and may be the majority of all tax for someone at a low overall income.
